# Automatic outlining of <summary>-s in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015 Community, `<summary></summary>` regions were automatically outlined, thus every such region formed a collapsable block.

I've downloaded VS 2017 Community, and automatic outlining of these have disappeared.

So, how to make automatic outlining collapse summary regions?

Comment: Not sure if it's Community edition behavior. It's configurable under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining.

Comment: @qxg Oh, I missed it, it was a bit confusing that you couldn't set to outline preprocessor regions, non-summary comments and summary comments separately...

Comment: @qxg By the way, thanks for notifying me about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is under **Debug -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining -> Show outlining for comments and preprocessor regions**. The comments include summary documentations, multiline comments - they cannot be set separately.